# How do I deal with date formatting in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, apache-kafka-connect

I am having issues figuring out the correct way to reformat/convert date fields in the js.

I am trying to create a report using the Kafka ODF streamer and sink connector and a js in between to handle transform, from an input EDR file.

**Sample O/P report**

```
MSISDN,DeleteReason,DeleteTime
12554564364661,3,2022-02-21T14:08:39.795Z
```

**Expected report format**

```
MSISDN,DeleteReason,DeleteTime
12554564364661,3,20220221140839
```

Note:- Want to transform the DeleteTime field to a different format "YYYYMMDDhhmiss", currently YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.MISZ .

**Transform section in the sink connector**

```
transforms: valueTransform
transforms.valueTransform.type: "com.openet.odf.transformer.ValueTransform"
transforms.valueTransform.script: "/opt/kafka/external-configuration/sink-hookpoint/valueTransform.js"
```

`eventTimestamp[or DeleteTime]` is an incoming date field declared as a string in the schema. ex:  `2022-02-21T14:08:39.795Z`

**Js Script**

```
  valueTransform.js: |
    function onValueTransform(_schema, _value) {
        var SchemaAndValue = Java.type('org.apache.kafka.connect.data.SchemaAndValue')
        var Date = Java.type('java.util.Date')
        
        var d = new Date.parse(_value.get("eventTimestamp"))
        var year = d.getFullYear()
        var month = ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
        var day = ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2)
        var hours = ('0' + d.getHours()).slice(-2)
        var minutes = ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2)
        var seconds = ('0' + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2)
        var modified_delete_time = year + month + day + hours + minutes + seconds        

        _value.put("eventTimestamp",modified_delete_time)
        
        return new SchemaAndValue(_schema, _value)
        }
```

I've tried using Date, SimpleDateFormat etc, but none of it is working and getting different errors with each attempt.

Comment: This works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/t9Lv5nmo/ When asking about errors, you need to a) make sure you look up how to use Date(), etc before asking here, b) google the error message(s) to solve the problem yourself and failing that c) tell us the exact error message you're getting. Your code is mostly fine, with the exception of trying to call `Date.parse` as a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing reasonable built-in. You can use Moment Timezone for [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com) in Javascript.

```
var actualDateTime = moment("2022-02-21T14:08:39.795Z");
var f = "YYYYMMDDhhmmss";
console.log(actualDateTime.format(f)) // By passing format into the format function to get it done
```

Comment: I believe OP is working in an environment where external libraries cannot be installed (the JS is executed inside a JVM)

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases, dealing with Dates may be a tricky process.

I would consider choosing a Dates library, for instance https://www.npmjs.com/package/luxon.

My first choise would be Moment.js, but the project is deprecated.

Using Luxon, you can rely on parsing and formatting utilities, something like that:

```js
DateTime.fromISO('2022-02-23T08:30:00').toFormat('yyyyMMddhhmmss')
```

Comment: I believe OP is working in an environment where external libraries cannot be installed (the JS is executed inside a JVM)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Forum.

I was able to use Calendar and SimpleDateFormat to achieve the desired results. Solution below

```
valueTransform.js: |
    function onValueTransform(_schema, _value) {
        var SchemaAndValue = Java.type('org.apache.kafka.connect.data.SchemaAndValue')
        var Date = Java.type('java.util.Date')
        var SimpleDateFormat = Java.type('java.text.SimpleDateFormat')
        var Calendar = Java.type('java.util.Calendar')        
                
        var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") 
        var EventDate = sdf.parse(_value.get("eventTimestamp"))
        sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
        var cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.setTime(EventDate)
        EventDate = cal.getTime()
        var formattedDate = sdf.format(EventDate)
        
        _value.put("eventTimestamp",formattedDate)
        
        return new SchemaAndValue(_schema, _value)
        }
```